# Google oAuth "expiry_date" format

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm making a request to Google oAuth in order to exchange the authorization code with an `access_token`, however, the response returned contains the `expiry_date` (instead of `expires_in` as in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)) with a value of `1474636927720`. This is not a timestamp format as I can see, any ideas what is it? PostgreSQL throws this `date/time field value out of range`. I have no problem storing this as a string but would like to know the value so that I can check if the token is expired or not.

Comment: kind of have to ask why it matters? it expires in an hour.

Comment: @DaImTo it could be, I'm not sure. The `expires_in` value surely should return `3600` but with this one, who knows what they changed (or might change in the future) because I'm using this token for `offline` API calls so I assume it "should" be longer than that (perhaps)

Comment: It really should return expires_in don't think I have ever seen the expiry_date one but that doesn't mean google cant be messing with something.   Offline access will give you a Refresh token which you can use to get a new access token.  Access token will never been good for more then an hour.

Answer (score 5):

I know it is kind of old, but I was just asking myself the same question. Right now I'm almost certain, that it's just Unix timestamp with milliseconds. In Java there is the method `System.currentTimeMillis()` for that and a [currentmillis website](https://currentmillis.com/) converts your value of `1474636927720` to `Fri Sep 23 2016 13:22:07 UTC`, which seems to be in line with the datetime of your post.

Comment: Can confirm that as of 2022 `expiry_date` is still Unix timestamp with milliseconds.

Comment: Funny thing is that I tried to convert this expiry_date using google convert ms to <unit measurement> and it gave me half a decade. Can confirm currentmillis website is up and says the expiry_date ends in an hour as expected.